# What’s the approved way to detect an incoming phone call from an iOS keyboard extension?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

How can I detect from an iOS Keyboard Extension if the keyboard is interrupted, for example an incoming phone call.

I have added observers for `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` in UIInputViewController's `viewDidLoad`. I have also added logging in those, plus logging in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`.

When I get an incoming phone call with my keyboard displayed -- I do not reliably get `applicationWillResignActive`, nor do I reliably get `viewWillDisappear`.

What’s the approved way to detect an incoming phone call from an iOS keyboard extension?

Answer (score -1):

I set Xcode "logging" breakpoints on the observers `willResignActive` and `didBecomeActive` to log the name of the breakpoint. Xcode logged `willResignActive` every time my phone received a call and `didBecomeActive` every time the call ended. I am realizing that calls to NSLog and "watching for them" in the Console App on my Mac may not be the correct approach. NSLog/Console seems flaky: i.e., drops NSLog messages.